# creating a whole site using asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net

```
i am new programmer i am using visual studio 2005 
i am making a project it is a e commerce site  



 1. what guideline should i follow ?
 2. what r de step i must take before creating de site ?
 3. where can i take help if i may get stuck ?
 4. any pdf file that can help me out ?
```

Comment: i am not so new to the enviroment

Comment: There are a lot of open source e-commerce sites in asp.net.  Even if you're doing this as a purely academic exercise, I would still  start there.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248/whats-a-good-free-and-open-source-asp-net-ecommerce-solution

Answer (score 1):

1. This is such an open ended and subjective question that it's impossible to answer as a simple bullet point.  please ask the question again on it's own.
2. Planning, planning, planning.  There is no substitute for it.  Also you should do a few (tester) web sites to get used to the environment and the language you choose.
3. You can get help here.
4. Not as such.  I suggest buying a book or 10 and reading through them and doing the samples.  Start off slow and basic.

**EDIT**

Also look at [WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix).  It will create a site for you that you just need to modify a bit.  It will also give you a good idea on some techniques.

**EDIT 2**

Also consider upgrading to VS2008 or VS2010.  Express editions of both a free from the Microsoft site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to programming and to the VS IDE, I would definitely suggest starting with something a little less ambitious than an E-Commerce site.

Start here:

http://www.asp.net/

**UPDATE:**

Since you are using Web Forms, you could start with the TailspinSpyworks (iBuySPy re-written for ASP.NET 4.0) E-Commerce site tutorial from Microsoft's Joe Stagner:

http://www.misfitgeek.com/op-ed/introducing-tailspinspyworks-webforms-sample-application

When you get to the checkout part, you need to be aware of a gotcha relating to the fact that an ASP.NET form can only have a single form tag. If you are integrating with PayPal and want to avoid messy JavaScript hacks, you can follow the steps I blogged about to get around this problem:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/03/08/Solution-to-ASPNET-Form-PayPal-Problem.aspx

Comment: BRO i am not so new to environment i have done with basic's but i am not getting idea how to develop an e-commerce site

Comment: Are you using Web Forms or MVC?

Comment: actually i am using Web forms